# Software to view metadata of an ISO file?

Tags: iso-image, metadata, udf, imgburn

I have been searching for the list of metadata field of an ISO file on Google but couldn't find anything. That made me think that there isn't any metadata in an ISO file, just the files content and their properties. However, today I find in ImgBurn that there is a field called `Imp ID`, which typically contains the software used to create the ISO file. I'm not sure if it is specific to the UDF and/or CDFS filesystem.

What are the other possible metadata fields in an ISO file? How can I see them?

Comment: Does sound like it's filesystem metadata though. Even if, what's the point in having metadata in your ISOs if nobody else does it?

Answer (score 1):

"UnISO" is *a plugin* for Altap Salamander (file manager).
http://www.altap.cz/salam_en/features/iso_viewer.html

"Viewing" (like if you were to "view" a text file, F3 in Norton Commander speak) an ISO shows something like:

```
Information on image

Number of sessions: 1
Session 1
  Number of tracks: 1
  Track: 1, ISO 9660 (Mode 1), Size: 557932 KBytes
    Volume:                   GRTMUPD_EN
    Volume Set:               GRTMUPD_EN
    Publisher:                MICROSOFT CORPORATION
    Data Preparer:            MICROSOFT CORPORATION, ONE MICROSOFT WAY, REDMOND WA 98052, (425) 882-8080
    Application:              CDIMAGE 2.52 (03/09/2004 TM)
    Volume Creation Date:     04/14/2008 12:00:00 PM
```

(And "clicking" to open an ISO, well, opens it :-).)

My point here is, that it appears that some sort of metadata exists, now you just need to find a program to display it to you.  (UnISO won't help unless you use Salamander.)